# Combining mySQL-Subqueries, dynamic BETWEENs?

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL and am trying to combine two Subqueries.
It is about time and excluding timespans.

The first (working) query fetches me every single valid day between two dates that are neigther saturday nor sunday (workdays):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN '2021-04-01' and '2021-07-15'
AND weekday(selected_date) <> 5
AND weekday(selected_date) <> 6
```

The second query fetches me the start and end-Dates of vacations from a table (UNIX-Timestamps) and formats these dates the same way the first query returns them as 2 separate values (from, to):

```
SELECT date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(from),'%Y-%m-%d') AS "from", date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(to),'%Y-%m-%d') AS "to" FROM vacation
```

I am trying to eliminate every occurence of dates that are within these Timespans between 'from' and 'to' from my second query within my first query.
The thing that gets me is that i dont know how to set multiple BETWEENs dynamically to filter out those ranges. The second query returns multiple 'from' and 'to' values which i want to use as a "NOT BETWEEN-Filter" for my first query.

I hope what i said makes sense to you.
I am glad for every answer pushing me towards the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join the two queries, and then a `NULL` check to exclude the matched rows.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (first query) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (second query) AS t2 ON t1.selected_date BETWEEN t2.from AND t2.to
WHERE t2.from IS NULL
```

It would also be better if the second query returned `DATETIME` values rather than formatted dates, so remove the calls to `DATE_FORMAT()`.